# Measuring total bandwidth utilized per server (windows)

Tags: windows, networking, vmware

I am looking for a way to monitor and report total bandwidth consumed by a windows virtual machine over a period of minutes to hours. I thought it would be easy to do this, but I can't seem to find a utility to do this.

Comment: A connection's properties window will show bytes sent/received.

Comment: If I wanted to see the utilization between 8:30 and 9:00 I wouldn't be able to isolate that easily. I guess I could note the count pre and post collection and do some simple math. Thank you.